# What is the Laplace transform of $\sin^2(t)$?

Tags: laplace-transform

What is the Laplace transform of $\sin^2(t)$?

My question is use $L(f^{'}(t))=sF(s)-f(0)$ to show that $L(\sin^{2}(t))=2/(s^2+4)$.

My approach was to integrate $\sin^2(t)$ to find $f(t)$, then use this to find $F(s)$ and $f(0)$.

However, using that method, I find that the Laplace transform of $\sin^2(t)$ is $(s/2-1/2(s/(s^2+4))$, not $2/(s^2+4)$.

This is also the answer I get using an online Laplace calculator.

So where am I going wrong, or is the question wrong?

Comment: try writing $\sin^2 (t) =\frac 1 2 (1 - \cos 2t)$

Comment: With [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) you can see the comparison between **Linkha**'s hint and the corresponding Laplace transform with the codes  LaplaceTransform[(sin t)^2,t,s]  and on the other hand this  LaplaceTransform[1/2(1-cos(2t)),t,s]  . Thus the right way is use the hint from the user using  (know the calculations of) a table of Laplace transforms and use the rules of calculate, combined with trigonometric idenitites, in this case.

Answer (score 2):

We have that
$$\cos(2x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)=1-2\sin^2(x)
\quad\Rightarrow \quad\sin^2(x)=\frac{1 - \cos (2x)}{2}.$$
Hence
$$f(t):=\int_0^t\sin^2(x) dx=\int_0^t \frac{1 - \cos (2x)}{2} \ dx
=\frac{t}{2}-\frac{\sin(2t)}{4},$$
and
$$F(s)=\frac{1}{2s^2}−\frac{2}{4(s^2+4)}.$$
Therefore 
$$L(\sin^2(t))=L(f^{'}(t))=sF(s)-f(0)=\frac{1}{2s}−\frac{s}{2(s^2+4)}-0=\frac{2}{s(s^2+4)}.$$
Check the final result [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laplace%20transform%20sin(t)%5E2).

P.S. There is an easier way to obtain the Laplace Transform of $\sin^{2}(t)$: transform directly the identity $\sin^2 (t) =\frac{1 - \cos (2t)}{2}$.

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks, both these responses are excellent. However, my lecturer insists that I have to use the L(f'(t)=sF(s)-f(0) identity, but that I CANT START by integrating sin^2(t). That's what has me so confused.

Comment: @Rockwallaby Is it better now?

Answer (score 1):

Just using the definition of Laplace transform and De Moivre's identity,

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin^2(t)e^{-st}\,dt &=& -\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(e^{it}-e^{-it}\right)^2 e^{-st}\,dt\\[0.2cm]&=&-\frac{1}{4}\left(\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-(s-2i)t}+e^{-(s+2i)t}\,dt-2\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-st}\,dt\right)\\[0.2cm]&=&-\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{s-2i}+\frac{1}{s+2i}-\frac{2}{s}\right)\\[0.2cm]&=&\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{2}{s}-\frac{2s}{s^2+4}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{2}{s(s^2+4)}}. \end{eqnarray*}$$
That also follows from $\frac{d}{dt}\sin^2(t)=\sin(2t)$ and $\mathcal{L}\left(\sin(2t)\right)=\frac{2}{4+s^2}$.

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks, both these responses are excellent. However, my lecturer insists that I have to use the L(f'(t)=sF(s)-f(0) identity, but that I CANT START by integrating sin^2(t). That's what has me so confused.

Comment: @Rockwallaby: you may compute a Laplace transform in any way you like, disregarding what your instructor tell you to do or not to do. To practice math is not to be restrained, and here you have plenty of (not so) different approaches.

Comment: I like the cut of your jibe Jack - but my lecturer seemed pretty sure. Thanks for your help mate.